# question about congruences

Tags: number-theory

I'm attempting to learn something about modular arithmetic.  I'm a retired engineer that obviously has a lot of time on his hands.

My question is this:

Given: $C_1 * x + C_2*y \equiv C_3*(x+y) \pmod K$, does this imply that $C_1, C_2 \text{and} C_3$ are congruent $\pmod K$.  Nothing is divisible by $K$.

Thanks,
Ron

Comment: Well, if that holds for *every* $x,y$, then, yes.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.  I believe that answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

We can produce examples of non-congruence. For instance, let $K=5$ and let $x=y=1$. Let $C_1=1$, $C_2=3$, and $C_3=2$.  There is really nothing special about these choices.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I unfortunately did not state the problem very well.  There are some other constraints such as C1,C2,X,Y are relative prime. I see now that was an obvious mistake.

Comment: It si happens that in the example above, they all are. If you edit your question to better reflect what you are looking for, perhaps I can find an answer.